# Error in compile-time arguments with AMD

Tags: opencl, intel, amd-processor

This is regarding compile time argument in openCL.
I have an array of constants of fixed size, and I am passing it as compile-time argument, as follows:

```
 -DCOEFF=0.1f,0.2f,0.5f,0.2f,0.1f
```

And in the Kernel, I am reading it as,

```
__kernel void Smoothing(__global const float *in, __global float *out)
{
    float chnWeight[] = {COEFF};

}
```

This way, using intel-SDK, I am getting a considerable amount of performance benefit, compared to passing the Coefficients as another argument to the kernel.

The problem is in AMD, this is not getting compiled. I am getting the following error :

```
0.2f:
Catastrophic error: cannot open source file "0.2f"

1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "0.2f".
Compilation terminated.
```

I understand that in AMD (comma) is also taken as a separating character for the compile time arguments, and this is causing the error.

Any help to solve this problem will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works for me using both Intel and AMD opencl. My AMD opencl version is "OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (937.2)". What version is producing this error?

Comment: I am using OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1311.2)

Comment: I switched to the latest AMD Windows OpenCL I could find (OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1268.1)) and now I get exactly the same problem as you. All I know to do is use an older OpenCL, or a somewhat ugly work-around such as compiling with `-DCOEFF0=0.1f -DCOEFF1=0.2f -DCOEFF2=0.5f -DCOEFF3=0.2f -DCOEFF4=0.1f` and using C code: `float chnWeight[] = {COEFF0,COEFF1,COEFF2,COEFF3,COEFF4};`

Comment: I may not be able to use your second suggestion, since my array length is not constant. `-DCOEFF=0.1f,0.2f,0.5f,0.2f,0.1f`, It can be `-DCOEFF=0.1f,0.2f,0.5f,0.2f,0.1f,0.1f,0.1,f` also. By keeping it in a single dynamic argument, I was actually enjoying a lot of flexibility as well as performance improvement (tested only in Intel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was introduced into AMD OpenCL sometime between versions 937.2 and 1268.1. Here is a work-around:

Replace,
`-DCOEFF=0.1f,0.2f,0.5f,0.2f,0.1f`
with
`-D COEFF=0.1f,0.2f,0.5f,0.2f,0.1f`

Comment: Thanks alot for this workaround. I tested this work around in intel and NVDIA also, and everywhere it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the string to `-DCOEFF="0.1f,0.2f,0.5f,0.2f,0.1f"`

It looks that the compiler is looking for the file "0.2f" and that is the second element, so after the first element and comma the compiler has already stopped interpreting the input as part of the COEFF define.

Comment: Using this way, eliminates the error reported. But, it will fail at the kernel, `float chnWeight[] = {COEFF}`.

Comment: Could you post the compiler error log at `float chnWeight[] = {COEFF}` ?

Comment: line(171)OpenCL Error: clBuildProgram failed with [CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE]. Actually, in the Kernel, I am trying to use the data in `chnWeight[]`, afterwards.